# LyX XeTeX and hyperref error hline

Tags: xetex, hyperref, lyx

I have a main LyX document with a number of child documents, which have English, Hebrew and Greek text. On compilation, I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@currentHref 

l.407 \hline

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

If I deselect the use of hyperref then everything compiles fine in LyX.

Strangely, though, if I leave the hyperref option selected and then maually compile the tex documents in the LyX temp directory, then it all compiles fine, the error simply doesn't appear.

So, I don't know if this is a package conflict (which if it is, why does manual compile work), or a LyX error.

Hyperref seems to be the culprit, since I can compile all the child documents separately, the link is a reference between child documents.

How can I get more information to debug this?